# Is there a way to detect auxiliary routes in class or html?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to be able to add a class in my html if there's an auxiliary route used.
I've spent some time today trying to find a way to do this. But it seems that aux routes are not done yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 days ago in CHANGELOG.md

```
 **router:** add Router and RouterOutlet to support aux routes ([6e1fed4]
```

So yes not yet supported, unless you take the latest version

Comment: I'll wait for the next rc. Thanks for you answer :)